# Send cross domain request with post method

Tags: php, javascript

How to send cross domain request from Javascript with Post method to Php file with large request data?

I have tried with $.ajax , $.post but have same issue as alerting POST failed.

Here is my HTML file[call.html] with Javascript at desktop::

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/
libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'http://localhost/GP/ALternate/file.php',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: '{"l":2}',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var value = responseData.someKey;
    alert(value);
  //document.getElementById('w').innerHTML = value.d;
        },
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert('POST failed.');
    }
});
</script>

<div id ='w'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my php [file.php] script at localhost:

```
<?php
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
    header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type');


 $f= $_GET["l"]; 

 echo "{'d' : '".$f."'}";


?>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: +1 and more info please. What are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: be aware you can't do it unless the server allows it

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use [Cross-origin resource sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) if you want to do POST requests to a different domain.

You will need your target server to add some response headers for this to work.

You can do GET using [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)

You can use jQuery library to handle most of the client side complexities for you. $.post(...)

Answer (score -1):

Use jQuery's [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/), with callback enabled.

Comment: getJSON will use GET method, not POST.

Comment: @BuddhiP I know that it uses `GET`, but even you haven't provided a solution to this. Your answer also says `You can do GET using JSONP`. And FYI, `$.post` doesn't do cross-domain requests. So, do check your answer as well.

Comment: If you know it uses GET dont give it as an answer, as GET/POST makes a  big difference in this case, and question specifically ask for POST. True that I've not written his program for him, but I mention where to look, which is the right thing. Would you care to explain why to do you say $.post wont do cross-domain requests? Just try giving it a url:'http://www.diff.domain.com' and see. post is just a shortcut method which replaces method on $.ajax call, and it can send posts to different domains. CORS is handled by XHR, not by jQuery.

Comment: If you know it uses GET dont give it as an answer, as GET/POST makes a big difference in this case, and question specifically ask for POST. True that I've not written his program for him, but I mention where to look, which is the right thing. Would you care to explain why to do you say $.post wont do cross-domain requests? Just try giving it a url:'diff.domain.com'; and see. post is just a shortcut method which replaces method on $.ajax call, and it can send posts to different domains. CORS is handled by XHR, not by jQuery.